# I'm running into overflow errors in the output of my code

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm simulating a point source for a research project and using the parameters I have here, my code should be outputting values on the order of 1.something + or - 0.00something*j and I'm getting values that are incredibly small. Like 3.8 * 10 ^-127.

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi

wvl = 1e-6
R = 50e3
k = (2 * pi)/wvl
N = 10.0
r0 = 0.1
D2 = 0.5
DROI = 4.0 * D2
D1 = (wvl * R)/DROI
x = np.linspace(-N/2, (N/2)-1, N)
y = np.linspace((N/2)-1, -N/2, N)
x1, y1 = np.meshgrid(x, y)

rho = np.sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2)

r1 = np.arctan2(y1, x1)

pointOne = np.exp(-1j*k/(2*R) * (r1**2))
pointTwo = pointOne / ((D1**2) * np.sinc(x1/D1) * np.sinc(y1/D1) * np.exp(-(r1/(4.0*D1))**2))

print pointTwo
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *slightly* incorrect when you said that

> Like 3.8 * 10 ^-127

I see that there is `exp(-986.96044011)` which is... I am not sure! :)
For example, `exp(-745)` is equal to `4.9406564584124654e-324` which is *much* smaller than you said. The most precise type in numpy is `float64`, and the value above is the smallest number it can take (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Soooo, I would say that this is impossible to calculate with numpy.

I think that there is no other way to calculate this except using `decimal` module and calculation with fixed point:

```
>> decimal.Decimal(-986.96044011).exp()
Decimal('2.336291362873238577842336912E-429')
```

**UPDATE**

```
from decimal import Decimal

factor1 = (D1**2) * np.sinc(x1/D1) * np.sinc(y1/D1)
factor2 = -(r1/(4.0*D1))**2

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        denom = Decimal(factor1[i][j]) * Decimal(factor2[i][j]).exp()
        real = Decimal(pointOne[i][j].real) / denom
        imag = Decimal(pointOne[i][j].imag) / denom
        print('{} {:+}j'.format(real, imag))
    print
```

I wouldn't copy/paste the whole output, but for the block with errors (i=3), which is output by numpy like:

```
[             -inf             +infj               inf             +infj
              -inf             +infj              -inf             +infj
  -1.33430914e+277 +1.39038774e+276j   2.71287770e+126 -5.24351460e+126j
   3.17716647e+062 -5.65262280e+062j   1.34513017e+045 -1.84387526e+045j
  -3.44573750e+040 +7.75538991e+039j  -3.43926477e+038 +2.50357768e+038j]
```

This code outputs the following:

```
2.581492951664502006187030185E+411 -5.762227636689223315330742967E+411j
2.122343066940105718447024076E+400 +1.467312608787517020408471212E+400j
2.397507101683903303475691738E+381 -2.280696798129953463268938559E+380j
-6.666386049218522221620946661E+346 +2.888168970661726622146331973E+347j
-1.334309136463760612094105714E+277 +1.390387738631591203923444430E+276j
2.712877702928865987066875589E+126 -5.243514596467982559177136476E+126j
3.177166469663657952353553473E+62 -5.652622800145748169241881476E+62j
1.345130165198935427036822984E+45 -1.843875257401926846810358724E+45j
-3.445737499727613189278598753E+40 +7.755389906593324611267619237E+39j
-3.439264771527389293832980697E+38 +2.503577682325662775720694139E+38j
```

As you can see, the correct tail matches.
Not sure if it's acceptable solution for you, since you are not able to works with that data with `numpy` anymore. `decimal` module lacks of support for complex numbers so you would have to implement it manually or find some third-party library for that purpose

Comment: Thank you Grief! Your comment about the exp function made me realize a few things and after changing the code around I was able to get it to output the data I wanted!

Comment: I kindly ask you to read this help article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Your responses have been really helpful, thank you! I realized I was using mixing up rho and r1 and using the wrong one in my code and this was causing the incredibly small values!